# How to create product review&rating programatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to export and import product reviews&ratings from old magento site to new magento site. I don't know how to do this without using an extension.

That's why I start with creating review and rating programatically. I'm able to create review by the following code snippet.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); //desired store id
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$review->setEntityPkValue(1);//product id
$review->setStatusId(1);
$review->setTitle("mytitle");
$review->setDetail("mydetail");
$review->setEntityId(1);                                      
$review->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());      //storeview              
$review->setStatusId(1); //approved
$review->setCustomerId(1);
$review->setNickname("Menickname");
$review->setReviewId($review->getId());
$review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$review->save();
$review->aggregate();
?>
```

But I don't know how to create **rating** programmatically. I'm totally blank about it. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: use the following tutorial : http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/add-product-ratings-programmatically-or-migrating-reviews-and-ratings-to-magento-61913.html

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add ratings for each of the 3 rating options (Price, Quality, Value) 
foreach($rating_options as $rating_id => $option_id):    
echo "Rating ID: {$rating_id} - ";    
echo "Review ID: " . $_review->getId() . " - ";    
echo "Product ID: " . $_product->getId() . " - ";    
echo "Option ID: " . $option_id . " - ";    
try {        
    $_rating = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
        ->setRatingId($rating_id)            
        ->setReviewId($_review->getId())            
        ->setCustomerId($_customer->getId())            
        ->addOptionVote($option_id,$_product->getId());    
    } catch (Exception $e) {        
        die(var_dump($e));    
    }
  endforeach;
  $_review->save();
  $_review->aggregate();
```

for more tutorial please see the following link 
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/add-product-ratings-programmatically-or-migrating-reviews-and-ratings-to-magento-61913.html

Comment: The link was expired, May i know about products reviews & rating bulk import using programatically in Magento 1? @Supravat M